# Uniqueness of represent object

Tags: category-theory

$F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$ is covariant functor.
If there're $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$ for which $\mathrm{Hom}(A,-) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(B,-) \cong F$ then $A \cong B$. I'm trying to use Yoneda's lemma: $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{Fun}}(F,F) \ni \mathrm{Id}_F \mapsto (B \rightarrow A)$, but i can't specify that it's isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt we have strict equation between hom sets, rather we have $\hom(A,X)\cong\hom(B,X)$ naturally in $X$ (meaning a collection of bijections $\phi_X:\hom(A,X)\to\hom(B,X)$ which make the arising squares commute for each arrow $X\to Y$).

To get an arrow $B\to A$, apply $\phi_A$ to $\def\id{\mathrm{id}} \id_A$, and to get an arrow $A\to B$, apply $\phi_B^{-1}$ to $\id_B$.

Use naturality to show that they are inverses to each other.